# List docs in a Dropbox Paper folder with API

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

Is there a way to use the [Dropbox API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers) to list docs in a Paper folder?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a way to list all Paper documents in a specific folder directly, but I'll pass this along as a feature request.

The closest thing is to use [/2/paper/docs/list](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#paper-docs-list)[[/continue](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#paper-docs-list-continue)], which let you list all of the Paper documents the user has either accessed (`filter_by=docs_accessed`) or created (`filter_by=docs_created`).

Comment: That would be great. I am interested in using the API to download some files that are in a specific folder - and doing so on a regular basis.